# Why AngularJS ng-model return [object%20Object] as value and not the option value (integer)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a select in AngularJS like:

```
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="newParticipantFormData.groupId" ng-options="item as item.name for item in newParticipantFormData.availableGroups.results track by item.id">

                    </select>
```

I hope that when the user selects a value in the "select" I get the value in newParticipantFormData.groupId, but I'm getting:[object%20Object], why?

In the console I can see the values, like you can see as follows:

```
 <option value="?" selected="selected" label=""></option>
 <option value="1819" label="Grupo 147258">Grupo 147258</option>
 <option value="1820" label="Grupo 258369">Grupo 258369</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the item id on select the option try this **:**

```
ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in newParticipantFormData.availableGroups.results"
```

**instead of**

```
ng-options="item as item.name for item in newParticipantFormData.availableGroups.results"
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.newParticipantFormData = {
      "availableGroups" : { "results" : [
         {
           "id": 1819,
           "name": "Grupo 147258"
         },
         {
           "id": 1820,
           "name": "Grupo 258369"
         }
      ]}
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select class="browser-default" ng-model="newParticipantFormData.groupId" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in newParticipantFormData.availableGroups.results"></select>
  {{newParticipantFormData.groupId}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="newParticipantFormData.groupId">
    <option ng-repeat="participant in newParticipantFormData.availableGroups.results" value="{{$index}}">{{participant}}</option>
</select>
```

The value shouldn't be the index, it can be anything that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `ng-options` as following

```
 ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in newParticipantFormData.availableGroups.results track by item.id"
```

Comment: doesn't work, select don't let to select any values, still blank but the values is there using your code.